# Getting accurate Mempool data quickly

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, bsc, pending-transactions, txpool

The mempool of one node isn't often the same as the mempool of another node, so when trying to get an accurate list of pending transactions at any given time, how can someone get that list?

I assume running your own geth node isn't good enough, I'm not sure what % of pending transactions won't be noticed.